# How to use a variable in SQLConnection.Open

Tags: vbscript

I have the below VBScript where I get a password as input parameter for establishing a SQL connection from a batch file,

VBScript:

```
Dim Pass
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Pass = args.Item(0)
MsgBox(Pass) ' The correct password which I get as input parameter shows up here.

Set SQLConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
SQLConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ABC,123;User ID=DEF;Password=Pass;Connect Timeout=0;"
```

The above doesn't work as its treating 'Pass' literally as password and not as a variable. However, if I hardcode the password there, the script works. Could anyone here please assist in how to pass variable to the `SQLConnection.Open`  method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rest of your parameters are good, this should work. In this case **Pass value** will be used, not the string "Pass"

```
sConString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ABC,123;User ID=DEF;Password="& Pass & ";Connect Timeout=0;"

SQLConnection.Open=sConString
```